# Parsing with JSON for API

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, flask, flask-restful

Building a Pokemon API that translates Pokemon descriptions to Shakesperean text.
I wanna take my Pokemon names from API endpoint: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151%27

Goal: When I'm running http://127.0.0.1:5000//api/v1/pokemon/all I wanna display what I get from the Pokemon endpoint in `json`. I feel I'm very close but there's one something I'm missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Code thus far:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import requests, json

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151%27"

payload = "{\n    \"name\": \"Julian\",\n    \"message\": \"Posting JSON data to Flask!\"\n}"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  'Cookie': '__cfduid=d819fa7205412e277649e0ce70eb381211600699952'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

@app.route('api/v1/pokemon/all')
def poke_names():
    to_parse =response.text.encode('utf8')
    requests.get(url, names=name)
    response_data = {name:"name", descrip:"description"}
    return jsonify(**response_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `response_data = {r}` is a set, not a dictionary

Comment: What does UTF8 have to do with the question? This page is UTF8. Python 3 strings are UTF8. There shouldn't be any need to decode anything

Comment: The code as shown cannot trigger this error. Did you change the focus of the question?

Comment: Apologies. Amended!

Comment: What is your question? Does the code result in an error? Does it produce unexpected output, and if so what would have been the expected output?

Comment: Honestly, I'm at a loss as what to add next in order to achieve the desired goal. 
If this format is not allowed let me know and I shall remove it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe my example will help you on your way to your goal.

```
from flask import Response

@app.route('api/v1/pokemon/all')
def poke_names():
    url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151"
    response = requests.get(url)
    return Response(response.text, mimetype='application/json')
```

or

```
@app.route('api/v1/pokemon/all')
def poke_names():
    url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151"
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    return jsonify(data)
```

I may not understand your goal and you are trying to give out all possible names.

```
@app.route('/api/v1/pokemon/all')
def poke_names():
    data = []
    url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151"
    while True:
        resp = requests.get(url)
        json = resp.json()
        data.extend(json.get('results', []))
        url = json.get('next')
        if not url: break
    return jsonify(data)
```

You should think about the usefulness of your project. At the moment it looks like you're just programming some kind of proxy.